# Storing earth observation derived attributes for polygons

Tags: postgis, database, imagery, satellite, big-data

I want to generate a number of vegetation related indices (NDVI, NDTI, etc., min/max/avg/std (pixel values)) from earth observation data for a large number of polygons during the entire growing season, roughly between March and November each year. The figures are about as follows: I have about one million polygons. Every day I will get new EO data (Sentinel-1/Sentinel-2) for about 20% of them. For each of these polygons I generate 10-20 indices based on the EO data. This gives me appr. 2-4 million records, every day. That makes appr. 500 - 1000 million during just one growing season (I´ll need to store at least 5 seasons).

The infrastructure within which I have to operate is predetermined and will have to be something based on either Oracle(Locator) or PostGIS. Personally I´d prefer PostGIS since OpenSource allows for much more flexibility.

My initial idea is to create a PostGIS database, which is partitioned based on year value. I thought about creating one attribute table where I create a new row for each date and each interpreted property (polygon geometries+id are stored in a separate table). It would look something like this:

[image: table_structure]

Since I have to do different interpretations depending on the geographical zone where the polygon lies, I also thought about creating a separate table for each zone. This will however make querying more difficult.

My questions are hence:

1. Does Oracle (Locator) or PostGIS as base for all this make sense
   at all or do I need to start asking for an account at an ESA
   DIAS/Google Earth Engine/AWS in order to be able to use cloud
   solutions?
2. If this indeed makes sense, wht is your opinion on my planned
   table structure?

Comment: Voted to close as off topic (or too broad, or primarily opinion based?); you should definetely ask this over at Databse Administrator SE. I do believe, though, that PostgreSQL can be sufficient as your backend (I worked with these and larger sizes), in a clustered environment (on AWS maybe). Go through the DB normalization rules to see where you can set up efficient relations. Check hstore/arrays for your key/value tuples (or check if the categories can actually be the key for normalization?). Keep the tables narrow, and use multi partition hierarchies (e.g. year, then zone, then time range).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Great to hear that the vast number of data should´nt kill my dream of using PostGIS as backend. I´ll definately have to do some thinking about the partitioning and structure in general (i.e. what other tables will come in and play a part in the game). Thank´s also for the off-topic comment, I posted the question on the DBA SE.